# Check file size using openXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I am using openXML library to read excel files. openXML provides two ways of reading the files.

1. Load all rows in memory at once
2. Load rows one by one using reader

The first approach is faster because once I have all rows in memory then I can use Parallel.ForEach for further processing whereas there is a limitation in this approach that if I load around 1 Million rows in memory then I get System.OutOfMemory Exception.

The second approach works fine for handling large data files but it is slow because it does not allow to iterate the rows parallelly.

I want to achieve the functionality that based on the file size user uploads, the code will decide which approach to use.

My question is that how can I get the file size using openXML.

If you have any other approach to solve this problem then please share that also.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't get the file size using C#?

Comment: I didnt find anything for getting the file size. If you know then please share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the file size, with .NET `System.IO` directly

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(path); // add appropriate try-catch

const int tresholdBigFile = 100_000; // bytes. You can use other value, just use other value that suits your need


if (fileInfo.Length < tresholdBigFile ) 
{
    // small file
}
else 
{
    // large file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to process each row in parallel after they are read (some pseudo-style, but should give you a hint how it could be done):

```
int maxDegreeOfParallelism = THREAD_COUNT;
var processor = new ActionBlock<Row>(r => ProcessRow(r), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
  {
     MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism
  });
while (var row = reader.ReadRow())
    processor.Post(row);
```

Then each row will be read one after another and processed by the `ProcessRow`-method on another thread up to `THREAD_COUNT`-threads in parallel.
NOTE: If the processing is way slower than the reading it is still possible that all rows are read before the first rows are processed and not in memory anymore. If that is the case you could check for the `InputCount` of the block and wait for it to get below a threshold before continuing to read and post rows.

Comment: Hi, your suggestion is really good but for now, the other solution is more relevant for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the uncompressed size of the xlsx file (or any OpenXML format file for that matter) you can use the [Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package(v=vs.110).aspx) class to open and inspect the [Parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.getparts(v=vs.110).aspx) for its stream lengths. This code will show how to do that:

```
long total;
using(var pack = Package.Open(@"c:\your\path\and\file.xlsx")) // also accepts a stream
{   
     total = (from pt in pack.GetParts()
                 select pt.GetStream().Length
              ).Sum();
}
Console.WriteLine("total uncompressed size {0}" ,total);
```

In my testing it didn't appear to read the whole file in memory to get the length but I only tested with files of around 30MB.